# Como parsear una fecha string a datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

hola me llega una fecha en formato mm/dd/yyyy desde la BD y cuando hago lo siguiente:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("12/29/2001");
```

error,No se puede reconocer la cadena como un valor datetime valido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso depende de la configuracion regional con el cual esta ejecutando el sitio web, se puede redefinir en el web.config o podrias indicarlo cuando conviertes

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("12/29/2001", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

la cultura `en-US` reconce ese formato de fechas

Comment: gracias funciono perfecto